# CKEditor event on element

Tags: events, ckeditor, keyboard-events

I'm writing my plugin and I am trying to set an event to an element, that I'll add to the editor. The event should act on the key enter.

Unfortunately, when I try to catch a 'key' or 'keydown' event nothing happens, but if I set 'click' event it's working great.

```
var element = editor.document.createElement('div');
element.setAttribute('data-type', 'example');
element.on('click', function() {
    alert("Hi");
});

editor.insertElement(element);
```

Can someone help a noob like me ? :D

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only listen to keyboard events in editing hosts (focusable elements). So just add your listener to editable element, e.g.

```
editor.editable().on( 'keyup', function( evt ) { console.log( 'keyup' ); } );
```